# How to make listview other row as unclickable when user tap first row

Tags: android, listview

I need help, when the user tap the first position i want other position should be unclickable and when user tap on 2nd,3rd and so on position i want to make only 1st position to be unclickable.

I have tried :

```
public class TypeOfTruckAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    List<TypeTruckPogo> list;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public String[] Current;
    TypeTruckPogo typeTruckPogo;
    public static HashMap<Integer,String> truckHashMap=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    private String[] arrTemp;
    boolean[] isEditTextVisible;
    int counter=0;
    int bestAvailiableCounter=0;
    public TypeOfTruckAdapter( Context context,List<TypeTruckPogo> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            truckHashMap.put(i,"");
        }
        arrTemp = new String[list.size()];
       isEditTextVisible = new boolean[list.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < isEditTextVisible.length; i++) {
            isEditTextVisible[i] = false;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }



    class Viewholder {
        TextView name;
        EditText nmbrOfTruck;
        LinearLayout ll;
        int ref;

        Viewholder(View view) {

            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            nmbrOfTruck = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_nmbr_of_truck_id);
            ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll4);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,  final ViewGroup parent) {
        final Viewholder holder;
        typeTruckPogo = list.get(position);
        if(convertView==null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_for_type_of_truck, parent, false);
            holder = new Viewholder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Viewholder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        // For position zero i have to set the text color to blue color,else dark gray color
        if(position==0){
            holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_color));
            holder.ll.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.mainBackGroundColor));
        }else{
            holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
            holder.ll.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.mainBackGroundColor));
        }
        // setting the name on the textview
        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getTypeOfTruckName());

        //setting the tag on edittext
        holder.nmbrOfTruck.setTag(position);
        //setting the viewholder position
        holder.ref = position;
        holder.nmbrOfTruck.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // Setting the User Input at specified Position
        /*Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = truckHashMap.keySet().iterator();
        while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
            String value=(String)truckHashMap.get(key);

        }*/
        // if user write on editText save the input by the user in specified position
        //truckHashMap is hashmap where I saving the position as a key and value as the user Input
        holder.nmbrOfTruck.setText(arrTemp[position]);

        holder.nmbrOfTruck.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                arrTemp[holder.ref] = s.toString();
            }
        });


        // holder.nmbrOfTruck.setText(truckHashMap.get(position) + "");
        Log.e("hsh",""+truckHashMap.get(position)+"");





        /*
        below i am facing the scrolling issue, when i scroll then alpha value is not behaving properly it seldom changing.
         */

        // user can press and unpress the single row,if he press single row then edittext is visiable and
        // if EditText is visiable then set TextView Color to white and Background color to dark Gray
        // if position 0 is selected then make other position as Unclickable and make alpha to other position to .2f
        //if other than 0 position is selected ,make 0 position row as unclickable and faint in color(alpha to .2f )for position zero.

        // Here i am binding the data if editText is visiable or not.

        if (isEditTextVisible[position]){
            //holder.nmbrOfTruck.setText(arrTemp[position]);
            Log.e("hshInsid", "" + truckHashMap.get(position) + "");
            Log.e("position", "" + position + "" + isEditTextVisible[position]);
            // if EditText is Visiable for specified position when user click make visiable for binding the data
            // because getView Recycle while scrolling so setting the visibility for specified position
            holder.nmbrOfTruck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // comparing zero index row of editText is visiable,if user selected zero index row then set textcolor to white and background color to dark gray

            if(list.get(position).getTypeOfTruckName().equalsIgnoreCase("BEST AVAILABLE")){
                // this is zero index item
                holder.ll.setEnabled(true);
                holder.ll.setAlpha(1);
                holder.ll.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
                holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));



            } else {
                // this is other item then zero index
                holder.ll.setEnabled(true);
                holder.ll.setAlpha(1);
                holder.ll.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
                holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }


        }else {
            // Binding the invisiable editText visibility.
            arrTemp[holder.ref] = null;

            holder.nmbrOfTruck.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//            truckHashMap.put(position, "");

             // default color of 0 row ,textView blue in color and background is light Gray(mainBackGroundColor)
            if(list.get(position).getTypeOfTruckName().equalsIgnoreCase("BEST AVAILABLE")){
                if(counter==0){
                    holder.ll.setEnabled(true);
                    holder.ll.setAlpha(1);
                    holder.ll.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.mainBackGroundColor));
//                    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getTypeOfTruckName());
                    holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_color));


                }else{
                    holder.ll.setEnabled(false);
                    holder.ll.setAlpha(.2f);
                    holder.ll.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.mainBackGroundColor));
                    holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_color));
                }



            }else{
                // default color other than 0 row ,textView blue in color and background is light Gray(mainBackGroundColor)
                if(bestAvailiableCounter!=0){
                    for (int j = 1; j < parent.getChildCount(); j++) {
                        parent.getChildAt(j).setAlpha(.2f);
                        parent.getChildAt(j).setEnabled(false);
                        holder.ll.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.mainBackGroundColor));
                        holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
                       // holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getTypeOfTruckName());
                    }
                }else {
                    for (int j = 1; j < parent.getChildCount(); j++) {
                        parent.getChildAt(j).setAlpha(1);
                        parent.getChildAt(j).setEnabled(true);
                        holder.ll.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.mainBackGroundColor));
                        holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
                       // holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getTypeOfTruckName());
                    }
                }


            }
        }


        holder.ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (holder.nmbrOfTruck.isShown()) {
                    holder.nmbrOfTruck.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    isEditTextVisible[position] = false;
                    typeTruckPogo.setIsUserTapped(false);
                    typeTruckPogo.setPosition(position);


                } else {
                    holder.nmbrOfTruck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    isEditTextVisible[position] = true;
                    typeTruckPogo.setIsUserTapped(true);
                    typeTruckPogo.setPosition(position);
                    if(position==0){
                        holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        holder.ll.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
                    }


                }
            }
        });


        Config.colorFont(context, null, holder.name, null);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Question is not clear, you want only one field to click while other don't ?

Comment: use Boolean variable to manage the things in onClick method

Comment: Suppose there is 20 item in a listview ,Scenerio 1 :When user select 0th row (means 0 position in a listview) then i want to make 1,2,3 upto 19th row as a unclickable. 2nd Scenerio: if user tapped on other row except 0(means 1st,2nd so on up to 19th row ) then i want 0th row to be unclickable

Comment: I am unable to conclude when user tap 0th position then how i will get the 1st,2nd upto 19th position in onClickListner

Answer (score 2):

use this bellow code and call `setRowOneClicked` when 1st row clicked, to achieve your requirement.

```
   public class TypeOfTruckAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private boolean rowOneClicked;
        //your code
        public void setRowOneClicked(boolean enable){
            rowOneClicked = enable;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,  final ViewGroup parent) {
            //your code goes on here
            if(position!=0 && rowOneClicked){
               convertView.setEnabled(false);
            }else{
               convertView.setEnabled(true);
            }
            return convertView;
        }

   }
```

Comment: this is a better idea ,let me try :)

Answer (score 0):

set a boolean flag in the model you use to populate listview , something like isEnabled. When user clicks on first position, check if  first position in OnItemClick method and set the other positions in model as false. then click again, same way apply logic for other condition u want

```
     listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                         if(position==0){
                            lst.get(0).isEnabled =true;
                            for(int i=1;i<lst.size();i++){
                            lst.get(position).isEnabled =false;
                            }  
                          }else{
                             lst.get(0).isEnabled =false;
                          }
                         }
                        if (!lst.get(position).isEnabled) {
                               return;
                        }else{
                            //your code
                        }
//In end set all Enabled
                     for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){
                            lst.get(position).isEnabled =true;
                            }
```

I hope this makes it a bit clear

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to create your **first element separately i.e (using a separate row for it)**. and rest of elements in listview. In this way it would be very easy to enable/disable click on items.